# dc (desk calculator) - hashes type

Tags: bash, perl, dc

Reading this page on TLDP: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/mathc.html

I've found the following command:

```
bash$ echo "16i[q]sa[ln0=aln100%Pln100/snlbx]sbA0D68736142snlbxq" | dc
Bash
```

And I was just wondering: someone knows what type of hash is that and how I can convert a simple text to generate that kind of hash?

thanks

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's what I have done.
Unfortunately I can't find what I am looking for.
I suppose there is a way in perl to encode or decode that type of hash or string, but I have no idea how.

Comment: `dc` doesn't have hashes. `[...]` creates a string.

Comment: [This site](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/dc.1.asp#Array_Operations) looks like a decent tutorial on `dc`.

Comment: I don't think `dc` is heavily used these days, so you may have to wait a while for someone who knows it to come around and translate that for you. Maybe the author of the web site can help you.

Comment: From the way that command is presented on tldp.org, it looks like it was designed to be confusing -- it's an example of the `dc experts` showing off how cryptic they can write things.

Answer (score 4):

Relatively good tutorial is [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/calculate-dc). Using it, you'll get the next decomposition:

- `16i` - the input will be hexadecimal (like in `bc` - `ibase=16`)
- `[q]` - the `[..]` mean string. So this store a string `q` to the top of stack. Usually the `[....]` is a series of commands stored for later execution (like a **macro**), in this case the command `q` - quit.
- the `s` - take the top of stack and store it to register identified by the next letter, so the `[q]sa` together in this case mean: store the the string `q` into register `a`
- same with the next, store the string `ln0=aln100%Pln100/snlbx` into register `b`
- the next `A0D68736142sn`, store the `A0D68736142` into register `n`. In this case not a string, but because we have input hexaadecimal, this is an hexadecimal number

The above is an like a preparation phase, translated into common programming language:

```
$a = "q";
$b = "ln0=aln100%Pln100/snlbx";
$n = 0xA0D68736142";
```

The stack is now empty (everything is stored in registres).

The next is the final calculation:

- the `l` mean take the the the value from the followed  register, and put it to the top of stack so the `lb` mean: take the value of register `b`.
- the `x` mean: execute it as an series of commands - in this case read it as `eval "$b";`
- the last `q` mean quit

now need decompose the `ln0=aln100%Pln100/snlbx` (content of register `b` - what is *eval*-ing.)

- `ln` - as above, take the value from the register `n` in our case: the hexa-number
- next is a tricky part: `0=a`, take the top of stack, and if it is `zero` execute the string (macro) stored in the registry "a" (in our case this is a "q" - quit), e.g. like:

```
if( $n == 0 ) eval "a"; #a contains "q" = quit
```

- if the `$n` isn't zero, take the content of regsiter `n` again (`ln`) (put to the top of stack)
- put the number `100` (it is hexa) to to top of stack
- `%` modulo the two numbers from the top of the stack (so: `$n % 0x100`) and put it to the top of the stack
- print the top of stack as an ascii string ( `chr($stack)` )
- `ln` take again the number `$n` (again, it comes to the top of stack)
- put `100` to the stack
- `/` divide the to numbers in the stack (result comes into the top)
- `sn` store the stack into the `$n` (replaces the original number)
- `lbx` - as above - eval the register b

So, in short:

- from the number `0xA0D68736142` stored in `$n`,
- modulo it by `0x100` get the last two digits, convert it to ascii and print it,
- divide it by `0x100` (removes last two digits) - and store it to `$n`
- repeat until nothing remained (zero)

For the `0xA0D68736142` you will get (use `man ascii`)

- `42` - `B`
- `61` - `a`
- `73` - `s`
- `68` - `h`
- `0D` - `\r`
- `A` (as 0A) - `\n`

Creating such hexsting from normal ascii string with perl

```
perl -E '$s=reverse("Bash\r\n");$s =~ s/(.)/sprintf("%02x",ord($1))/seg;say uc $s'
```

prints

```
0A0D68736142
```

or

```
perl -E '$s=reverse("Stackoverflow rocks\n");$s =~ s/(.)/sprintf("%02x",ord($1))/seg;say uc $s'

0A736B636F7220776F6C667265766F6B63617453
```

and

```
echo "16i[q]sa[ln0=aln100%Pln100/snlbx]sb0A736B636F7220776F6C667265766F6B63617453snlbxq" | dc
```

prints:

```
Stackoverflow rocks
```

*Ps: with `dc` is one strange thing - it is much-much easier to read and understand a "program" as creating one.* :)

Comment: @Hector this is not "dc-string", but simple hexadecimal values of the string. You can create some manually with `man ascii` or see the edit for perl script.

Comment: @Hector - And if youre satisfied with the answer, you can also click Accept (the green mark) at the answer... <grin> :)